# Magento 2 How to get the configurable products related all child products in list page using object manager?

Tags: blocks, magento2.2.2, list.phtml

> Magento 2 in how to get the configurable products related all child (simple products QTY) in list page using object manager?

Please give me a solution this questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Its Working .

<?php
             $productId = 161;
              $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
              $currentproduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);                $configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);       
              $_children1 = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
              foreach ($_children1 as $child1) {
               echo $child->getsku();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all simple products associate to configurable product:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
foreach ($_children as $child){
echo "Here are your child Product Ids ".$child->getID()."\n";
}
echo "count: ".count($_children);
```

Comment: its not working?

Comment: Have you give $product_id ?